# Get Info about a secret Facebook Group via Graph Api

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am not able to use the facebook graph api to get information about secret groups where i am not the admin. Is there a trick to change this?
This is the group id where i am trying to get the information: 1521273261491007
All the other groups are working fine for me...
Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only get access to secret groups you manage, with the `user_managed_groups` permission and the `/me/groups` endpoint. There is no way to get access to groups you don´t manage anymore (except for public ones).